# How to get wikipedia out-links of an article in python?

Tags: python, mediawiki, wikipedia, mediawiki-api, pywikibot

I want to get the out-links of wikipedia articles. What I mean by out-linkes are the links in `What links here` section in wikipedia articles.

For instance, consider the `data mining` wikipedia article. `What links here` section of this article is in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/Data_mining

I tried to used `pywikibot` as follows.

```
import pywikibot as pw

site = pw.Site('en', 'wikipedia')
print([
    cat.title()
    for cat in pw.Page(site, 'data mining').categories()
    if 'hidden' not in cat.categoryinfo
])
```

However, it seems like the `categories` in pywikibot is different to out-links of wikipedia articles. Therefore, I am wondering how to do this in python.

Note: I am not limited to pywikibot and happy to explore other libraries such as `mediawiki`.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`Page.embeddedin()`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/api_ref/pywikibot.html?highlight=backlinks#pywikibot.page.BasePage.embeddedin) and [`Page.backlinks()`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/api_ref/pywikibot.html?#pywikibot.site.APISite.pagebacklinks) methods. You could also directly use the equivalent modules of MediaWiki's API:

- [Backlinks](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Backlinks)
- [Embeddedin](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Embeddedin)

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. it would be really great if you could tell me what is the difference of 'embeddedin' and `backlinks`? Does it return similar restults? Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: @EmJ At the top of the [WhatLinksHere page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/Data_mining), you'll notice a few filters: `Hide transclusions | Hide links | Hide redirects `. WhatLinksHere, by default, retrieves a combination of [tranclusions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Transclusion) (embeddings) and [backlinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backlink). Using the above methods/modules you should be able to retrieve any of them.

Comment: Thank you very much. The details you have provided were very useful for me to understand the difference :)

Comment: Hi, I did some testing of the methods you suggested me. It looks like pywikibot suggests backlinks such as `[[en:User talk:202.58.134.131]]` which I am not interested on. Is it possible to filter such irrelevant backlinks from the list? Looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you :)

Comment: Use the `namespaces` argument.

Comment: thank you very much for the comment. However, I still could not figured out how `namespaces` is used. Would you be able to show some example to follow? thank you very much. I look forward to hearing from you :)